# Как получить epoch time на момент месяц, год назад?

Tags: python

Получаем текущую отметку epoch time (количество прошедших секунд) сейчас

```
import time    
epoch_time = int(time.time())
```

Как получить производные от текущей отметки:

- месяц назад
- три месяца назад
- год назад
- два года назад?

Просто отнимать количество секунд в месяце, году - видится плохим вариантом, т.к. в месяцах разное количество дней...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, вам надо преобразовать timestamp в дату с помощью функции `fromtimestamp` библиотеки `datetime`, а затем вычесть из даты нужное кол-во дней / месяцев / лет с помощью `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`

```py
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta
import time

epoch_time = int(time.time())

current_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)

month_ago = current_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
three_month_ago = current_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=3)
year_ago = current_date = current_date - \
    dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=1)
two_years_ago = current_date = current_date - \
    dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=2)


print(current_date)
print(month_ago)
print(three_month_ago)
print(year_ago)
print(two_years_ago)

# 2020-04-19 09:41:28
# 2023-03-19 09:41:28
# 2023-01-19 09:41:28
# 2022-04-19 09:41:28
# 2020-04-19 09:41:28
```

P.S.: Поскольку вы не указали определение *"месяц назад"*, я посчитал, что это значит *"день в предыдущем месяце не больший дня в текущем"*. Так, например, если бы вы вызвали этот код 31.03.2023, то дата месяц назад была бы 28.02.2023. Если вам хочется вычесть количество дней, вы можете использовать `days=31`, а не `months=1`. Если вы хотите получить количество день в текущем месяце, вы можете использовать модуль `calendar`:

```py
import calendar

days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(current_year, current_month)[1]
```

UPD: Чтобы получить именно timestamp, вы можете использовать метод `.timestamp()`. Пример:

```py
current_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
print(int(current_date.timestamp()))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно, я не знал про либу dateutil.relativedelta